# Pass d3 index to variable that creates striped pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I asked this once before, but I wasn't asking the right question so I've deleted that old post and am hopefully asking again in a way that makes sense.

I have translated these instructions (https://bl.ocks.org/jfsiii/7772281) for creating striped patterns in SVG into d3:

```
var twoDefs = svg.append('defs')
    .data(items)
    .enter()
   .append('pattern')
   .attr('id', 'twoStripes')
   .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
   .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45)')
   .attr('width', 4)
   .attr('height', 4);

 //to def add rect.
 twoDefs
   .append('rect')
   .attr("x", 0)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr('width', 2)
   .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('fill', 'purple');
 twoDefs
   .append('rect')
   .attr("x", 2)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr('width', 2)
   .attr('height', 15)
   .attr('fill', 'yellow');
```

It is invoked during the creation of bars via the following command:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(items)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("class", function(d, i) {return "bar " + items[i].characters.first_character.character;})
.attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.starting_line;})
.attr("y", function(d, i) {return y(d.location);})
.attr("width", function(d, i) {return d.duration;})
.attr("height", 15)
.attr("fill","url(#twoStripes)");
.call(tip)
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

This fills the bar with the purple and yellow striped line any time the             `.attr("fill","url(#twoStripes)");` statement, rather than a color code, is attached to a rect.

The problem I am running into, though, is that any attempt to actually include color codes from my data in the twoDefs rectangles (via `.attr('fill',function(d,i) {return "#" +  items[i].characters.first_character.color});` rather than `.attr('fill', 'purple');`, for example) always results the first record in the array being evaluated rather than the record of the item that actually is meant to be evaluated.  I know it's because there's no explicit link between twoDefs and bar, but I don't know what I need to do to modify my pattern-creation bit to also include the necessary index information to call to the right records.

The data in `items` is pretty long, but here's a couple of records for reference:

```
   {
        "location": "Lazarus' tomb",
        "starting_line": 919,
        "line_text": "That blyssyd Lord þat here ded apere!",
        "duration": 1,
        "characters": {"first_character": {
            "character": "Lazarus",
            "color": "FFCC00"
        }}
    },
    {
        "location": "Lazarus' tomb",
        "starting_line": 920,
        "line_text": "We beleve in yow, Savyowr, Jhesus, Jhesus, Jhesus!",
        "duration": 1,
        "characters": {
            "first_character": {
                "character": "People",
                "color": "7DB2B2"
            },
            "second_character": {
                "character": "Weepers",
                "color": "7D7DB2"
            },
            "third_character": {
                "character": "Mary Magdalene",
                "color": "CC0000"
            },
            "fourth_character": {
                "character": "Martha",
                "color": "339900"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "location": "Lazarus' tomb",
        "starting_line": 921,
        "line_text": "Of yower good hertys I have advertacyounys,",
        "duration": 1,
        "characters": {"first_character": {
            "character": "Jesus",
            "color": "00CCCC"
        }}
    }
```

Comment: Post `items` as well in your question.

Comment: Just a side note: For these kinds of illustrations I particularly like the *Pattern Fill* project by Irene Ros. There is a nice [post](https://bocoup.com/weblog/using-svg-patterns-as-fills) of hers explaining the use of these patterns along with some D3 code.

Comment: items is a pretty huge file, but I'll edit to add a snippet.